# Script Code Syntax ...html Comment inside?

Tags: javascript, syntax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HTML comments in a javascript block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780047/html-comments-in-a-javascript-block)

Hello im cleaning a web page from comments and other stuff.

I just found this `<!--` but i dont understand why start with `<!-- and close with -->`

I use that to comment out something on html.. but here?? look at it

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
$("ul.menubbcl").superfish({        
    animation: {height:'show'},   // slide-down effect without fade-in 
    delay:     1000,           // 1.0 second delay on mouseout
    autoArrows : true 
}); 
//--></script>
```

Can somebody explain me this. pls

Comment: To support very old browsers which would render the script as text in the page rather than execute it.

Comment: Your my hero!, thanks ;) really i ask just a minute ago jajaja

Comment: Funny thing: the snippet uses jQuery, but I don't think even jQuery supports such old browsers (although it probably degrades gracefully).

Comment: Wait, doesn't this will create a `SyntaxError` for `<!--`?

Comment: @Derek see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5780076/781965) - `<!--` is apparently ok, but `-->` isn't, hence the `//` beforehand.

Comment: @Jeff - How does `<!--` even valid... (although I know it is valid in JavaScript)

Comment: @Derek I had a browser through the [ecma specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) and nothing really jumped out as to why it's ok, so I suspect it's actually just that browsers can cope with it as they do with minor syntax errors, or that they know that old websites use this exact trick, so they don't complain about it.

Comment: @Jeff - I tried `window;<!--;window;` and it comes out ok, so I guess the browser just ignores it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is for browsers that do not support Javascript. Supplying HTML comment tags around it will prevent it from being rendered as text in such browsers.

Comment: Thanks!! always great to learn something new

Comment: @Monclee Don't forget to accept the appropriate answer using the "tick" button on the left :)