# Why is it that script will run from using jquery's html but not from using innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, innerhtml

So I am a little confounded here. I do not understand why script executes when placed with jquery's `.html()` but not with `innerHTML`. I looked at the source code for jQuery's `.html` and it still seemed that `innerHTML` was being used. Can anyone explain this behavior?

I came across this during an ajax response. I was getting back html and a `script` tag with some javascript in it, and I usually use `html`, but for some reason had used `innerHTML` this time thinking there was no difference.

I understand that this might seem to be localized, so I made a jsFiddle with a timeout that behaves similar to an ajax response in order to highlight the issue.

**[jsFiddle demonstrating the behavior](http://jsfiddle.net/sKm8N/)**

Comment: The HTML standard explicitly mentions that `script` elements are not evaluated when set via `innerHTML` (http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/dom.html#dynamic0): *"Note: `script` elements inserted using `innerHTML` do not execute when they are inserted."*

Comment: @FelixKling - Thank you for the link. Not sure why I thought otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell from a bit of breakpointin', jQuery will *try* to use `innerHTML`, but, failing that, it'll fall back to emptying the target element, and appending the new content via the DOM.

*Update: see Felix Kling's comment below; basically, if the string content to be inserted contains script or style/link tags, jQuery won't use straight `innerHTML`*

When that happens - and it does in your case - the content goes through a function called `domManip` which I don't claim to fully understand, but it does specifically look for and evaluate scripts.

So the short answer is: jQuery's not using `innerHTML` after all. Wish I could give you a better step-by-step of exactly what happens, but I don't know my way around jQuery's source well enough. I just set a breakpoint (at line 6074 in jQuery-1.9.1.js; the point where jQuery decides *not* to use `innerHTML` after all) and stepped around the source a little.

Comment: +1 - Good analysis. I noticed that it goes through an interesting process as well but could not for the life of me find where `eval` would get used in the source code. This answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1197585/1026459 , seems to indicate that `eval` is used on scripts as well.

Comment: @TravisJ yeah, the script content gets passed to `globalEval()` (see line 597) which does indeed use `eval`

Comment: The test happens in https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.9.1/src/manipulation.js#L230. `!rnoInnerhtml.test( value )` evaluates to `false`. At the beginning of the file, it is defined as `rnoInnerhtml = /<(?:script|style|link)/i`, i.e. it tests for `script` tags. `.append` is then used instead, which does what you explained (I didn't look into it any further though).

Comment: @FelixKling Ah, that's the trigger. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: @Flambino - Actually, I do not think that `globalEval` uses `eval`. What it does is build a new script element and then append it to the document head. Thank you for the help though, definitely helped me understand this issue!

Comment: @TravisJ No problem, thanks for the checkmark. But I have to say that `globalEval()` does use actually use `eval` ([see here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.9.1/src/core.js#L577)). No scripts are inserted in the document head (at least not that I can see here in Chrome)

Comment: @Flambino - Ah, you are correct! But so am I :P I wonder when they changed it, this project was using an older version (1.4.4). http://pastebin.com/xWaYtC6y