# Is <!-- a valid comment delimiter in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is `<!--` a valid comment delimiter in JavaScript?

```
var foo = 'foo'; <!-- Is this a valid single-line comment?
```

Comment: `var foo = 'foo'; //This is a single line comment in js`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18638833/14955

Comment: Please can those who down-voted explain why?

Comment: always ["use strict";](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode))

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML comments in a javascript block?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780047/html-comments-in-a-javascript-block)

Comment: Are you asking because it isn't working? Or because it does work and you don't know why?

Comment: people probably downvoted without thinking because it _looks_ like a dumb question...

Comment: @BenAston I originally downvoted because it just seemed like something you could test and **know** that the comment doesn't work and shouldn't be used.  It reads like a question where someone just asks things for the sake of asking and doesn't really have a reason behind what they're asking.  And then, I saw Thilo's link, was very surprised, and upvoted your question and the answer.  If you could edit your question, incorporating your response to j08691 I think a lot of the downvotes would go away, or at least stop happening.

Comment: You seem to have a tendency of posting very short or vague questions at times, sometimes simply repeating the title in the body. The question title serves as a summary, and the body is a place for you to elaborate on the title, not just to repeat it, and it's clear that the context that @j08691 prompted you about was essential to the question and could well have been included in the body to begin with.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, [it apparently is](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-html-like-comments).

This syntax was included to cater for browsers that do not support JavaScript, to avoid them rendering the code inside `<script>` tags. This was more important in the early days of the Web, when a large proportion of browsers did not support JavaScript.

Both [`<!--`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#prod-annexB-SingleLineHTMLOpenComment) and [`-->`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#prod-annexB-HTMLCloseComment) delimit single line comments.

```js
<!-- this is treated as a single line comment
--> and this is treated as a single line comment
```

So you can write your script tags using the following syntax:

```html
<script>
<!--
console.log('this is my code')
-->
</script>
```

Note that [the Wikipedia page on JavaScript syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript_syntax#Comments) does not mention this.

Comment: `--> is logged in :` actually looks nicer than `// is logged in :`

Comment: @dandavis It looks nicer in plain text, but it doesn't get highlighted as a comment in my text editor, so I think I'll stick with `//`

Comment: @jasonscript: Could file a bug with your text editor for not supporting this obvious Javascript syntax that everyone totally knows about ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is - but its rare to see these days. Typically we see C single line and C++ multi-line style commenting used.

> One-line comments with the HTML comment-opening sequence. Note that
>   the JavaScript interpreter ignores the closing characters of HTML
>   comments.

source : http://www.javascripter.net/faq/comments.htm

Answer (score 3):

To give a bit of context, way back when Javascript and the `<script>` tag were new things, there was the danger that if you put a `<script>` element full of script on your page, some browsers that didn't know what it was would just show its contents on the page.

The solution was to define the Javascript language so that `<!--` and `-->` are treated as single-line comments (the latter only when it occurs at the beginning of a line with the optional inclusion of whitespace and/or multiline JS comments). This way, the HTML renderer would see all of the script as a comment, and the JS interpreter would simply ignore these lines and process the rest.

So you could do this (and presumably still can):

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--

     document.write("<blink>HELP!!!! I'm using 1990's Javascript!!!</blink>")

--></script>
```