# Is `-->` a valid single line comment delimiter in JavaScript, in Web browsers?

Tags: javascript

`<!--` [is a valid comment delimiter](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-html-like-comments) in JavaScript, in Web browsers.

But is `-->` also a valid comment delimiter in JavaScript, in Web browsers?

```js
--> console.log('is this commented out?')
```

[This is the relevant grammar](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-annexB-HTMLCloseComment), but I find it difficult to parse.

[image]

**Edit:** I now think it is a valid single line comment, per the information in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29171008/38522), but the information in that answer still leaves room for ambiguity for me, so I am leaving this question open.

Comment: HTML comments start with `<!--` and end with `-->`, what exactly is your question

Comment: `<!--` begins a comment and `-->` ends a comment. There is no such thing as a "single line comment delimiter". See See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757051/how-to-comment-uncomment-in-html-code

Comment: @Pointy this is a question about JS comments, not HTML comments

Comment: @Hamms how do you know from what's in the OP?

Comment: see https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_comments.asp

Comment: OP linked to an ECMAScript spec

Comment: The new syntax is meant to address old (*really* old) code. `<!--` opens an HTML comment block, and `-->` ends one. There's literally no reason at all for newly-written JavaScript code to use HTML comments.

Comment: @Hamms yes thanks I see that now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My interpretation of this is that a line like `--> comment` will in fact work as a comment.

This can be interpreted as the string `-->` followed by a [SingleLineCommentChars](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-SingleLineCommentChars) sequence, which fits the definition of an [HTMLCloseComment](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-annexB-HTMLCloseComment). An HTMLCloseComment all by itself on a single line fits the definition of a [SingleLineHTMLCloseComment](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-annexB-SingleLineHTMLCloseComment), which is one of the valid forms of a [Comment](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-annexB-Comment)

This can be verified in ECMAScript parsers like [esprima](https://esprima.org/demo/parse.html?code=%3C!--%20open%0A--%3E%20close%0A%2F%2F%20standard). An input of

```js
<!-- open
--> close
// standard
```

produces:

```
{
    "type": "Program",
    "body": [],
    "sourceType": "script",
    "leadingComments": [
        {
            "type": "Line",
            "value": " open",
            "range": [
                0,
                9
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "Line",
            "value": " close",
            "range": [
                10,
                19
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "Line",
            "value": " standard",
            "range": [
                20,
                31
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Of course, just because you *can* doesn't mean you *should*, particularly in this situation.

Comment: I guess they designed it that way to be really forgiving incase someone left some code inside a `<script>` _after_ a closing `-->`.

Comment: that seems likely!