# How do I check if a script is running as a ES6 module (so that it can `export`), in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I'd like to make a Javascript file that

- `export`s its content (e.g. a class) if it can `export` (e.g. it has been loaded with `<script type="module">`)
- and otherwise, assigns its content into the global variable such as `window` and `global`.

---

For example, let's assume such a file `print.js`.

#### Case A

One can use it like:

```html
<script type="module">
    import print_things from "./print.js";
    print_things("Javascript innovation");
</script>
```

#### Case B

or,

```html
<script src="./print.js"></script>
<script>
    print_things("Hmmmmmmm.");
</script>
```

---

Currently, using `export` makes the script throw an error in **Case B**: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export`. So it has to know whether `export` is available on the environment whereon it runs, in order to support the both use cases. How do I do this?

Comment: You should use webpack or similar to be able to always use `import` in ypur code, but output it without

Comment: I think you've got it the wrong way round. A file does not dynamically export something or not depending on how it is included. Rather it should be included in the right way, depending on whether it's an ES6 module or not.

Comment: @Bergi Oh, then the best way I should do would be maintaining one file for one thing, generating two separate files from it (using _Webpack_ that xjmdoo suggested), one for ES6 module users, another one for non-module users, and providing them.. Did I understand it right?

Comment: @K._ Yes. (Or leave applying webpack etc to your users and provide only ES6 modules)

Comment: Reminds me [How it feels to learn JavaScript in 2016](https://hackernoon.com/how-it-feels-to-learn-javascript-in-2016-d3a717dd577f)... I think I should get used to work with them.

Comment: Was Case B supposed to be `print_things` instead of `window.print`?

Comment: @CiroSantilli新疆棉花TRUMPBANBAD I guess so. Well, I’m not sure what younger me was thinking back then.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37656592/define-global-variable-with-webpack

Answer (score 5):

(**Note: you probably shouldn't use this in the real world**, but it *is* totally valid and does exactly what you want.)
Here's an implementation of your `print.js`:

```js
function print_things(msg) {
   console.log(msg)
}
if(0)typeof await/2//2; export default print_things
```

```html
<script type=module>
   // (renamed to avoid name collision)
   import print_things2 from "https://12Me21.github.io/external/print.js"
   print_things2("Javascript innovation")
</script>

<script src="https://12Me21.github.io/external/print.js"></script>
<script>
   print_things("Hmmmmmmm.")
</script>
```

This syntax will "hide" the export statement from non-module scripts, because **`await/2//2; ...`** is parsed differently depending on context:

- In a *module* or *async function*:
  `await`(operator) `/2/`(regexp) `/`(divide) `2`(number)
- In a normal *script*:
  `await`(variable) `/`(divide) `2`(number) `//2 ...` (**comment**)

When it's parsed as a comment, the rest of the line is ignored. So, the `export` statement is only visible to module scripts.

Here is the relevant part of the specification:
[15.8 Async Function Definitions > Syntax > AwaitExpression > Note 1](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-functions-and-classes.html#prod-AwaitExpression)

#### Compatibility

As a non-module script, it should work in *any* browser (even ancient versions of Internet Explorer etc.), and is still valid with `"use strict"` enabled

However, loading it as a module requires support for "top-level await", which was added a few years after modules themselves (~2021 vs ~2018), so keep that in mind.
(It also works with nodejs, in either mode)

I've used this trick in a library that I wrote, and it's been working fine in multiple environments for several months.
However, it has caused some problems with external tools (frameworks, compilers, minifiers, etc.)

Comment: Holy, [commenting with `<!--` is a thing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18638833/4510033)? Didn’t know that. And that’s clever.

Comment: I have a potentially better option now, which works in node.js: `if(0)+typeof await/2//2; export ... ` (or just `0&&await/2//2; export ... `)

Comment: so it turned out that the html comments thing ONLY worked in firefox, and other browsers would just throw an error when running it as a module. fortunately, this await parsing trick works much better

Comment: cool! do I understand correctly that `if(0)` is not really necessary for the trick to work, but it prevents unnecessary execution of code at runtime whose result isn't used anyway, right? In both cases one would "calculate" `NaN`. But with `if(0)`, it seems to me that one can actually drop `typeof` without disadvantage. The code is not executed, so no exception. At least it works in the snippet... Ah, just realized you have the short version in your own comment!

Answer (score 2):

Browsers that understand `type=module` should ignore scripts with a `nomodule` attribute. This means you can serve a module tree to module-supporting browsers while providing a fall-back to other browsers.

```
<script type="module" src="module.js"></script>
<script nomodule src="fallback.js"></script>
```

Comment: If I go with this method, do I have to have two files for one thing?

Comment: Yes, but that does not mean you have to maintain two files separately. You can always use something like `webpack` to transpile your code for fallback support.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [UMD](https://github.com/umdjs/umd) (universal module definition). Namely, [this example](https://github.com/umdjs/umd/blob/master/templates/commonjsStrictGlobal.js)

```
(function (root, factory) {
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
        define(['exports', 'b'], function (exports, b) {
            factory((root.commonJsStrictGlobal = exports), b);
        });
    } else if (typeof exports === 'object' && typeof exports.nodeName !== 'string') {
        // CommonJS
        factory(exports, require('b'));
    } else {
        // Browser globals
        factory((root.commonJsStrictGlobal = {}), root.b);
    }
}(typeof self !== 'undefined' ? self : this, function (exports, b) {
    // Use b in some fashion.

    // attach properties to the exports object to define
    // the exported module properties.
    exports.action = function () {};
}));
```

Comment: Is it impossible to achieve this with ES6 modules, instead of UMD (CommonJS and AMD)?

Comment: You can transpile ES6 modules to use the UMD header

Comment: yep! check out the [browserify](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-es2015-modules-umd/) plugin

Answer (score 0):

Just as a small addendum to other answers. Within a browser (I'm not sure about Node.js) module mode of a script can easily be recognized by:

```
const isModule = (document.currentScript == null);
```

at least if the above line is executed in the main part of the script, i.e. not in an event-handler or callback. See [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript)
This answer, however, does NOT solve the OP's actual intent of a conditional export, because using the above boolean to then conditionally export variables would throw a "SyntaxError: export declarations may only appear at top level of a module" or similar. Therefore the other answers are the ways to go. It might still be that there are use cases where the above recognition could be useful.